# Loop inside the gridview on devexpress

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I am new on devexpress,so I have a simple question here.what is the equal of the this code on devexpres gridview.

here is the my code

```
for (int i = 0; i <gridView1.RowCount; i++)
{
    string Name = gridView1.Rows[i].["ColumName"].toString();                                  
}
```

**I looked at the a method something `gridView1.Rows[i]` but ,not available.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [Traversing Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument5299) in the DevExpress support center. Looks like this would work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
{
    DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(i);
    string name = row["ColumnName"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.VisibleRowCount; i++)
{
int currentRowHandle = gridView1.GetVisibleRowHandle(i);
string value = grid.GetCellValue(rowHandle,grid.Columns["Column Name"]);
}
```